# Packaging TideSDK Application with Custom Icon

Tags: installation, icons, tidesdk

I was able to package my desktop application on my Windows machine and the app runs. This is all great. But the icon assigned to the file after I run the installation from the generated MSI file is the default Titanium icon.

I've done what is suggested on this thread

[Windows Packaging Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662279/windows-packaging-icon)

for the Tide-SDK 1.3.1 beta but no luck, is there any other way I can change the default Tide SDK assigned to the app by the installer to my customized icon? I have the tiapp.xml working just want the same icon to be assigned to my app by the installer too

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this and it worked fine for me. I put a 512x512 png in my `Resources/` directory and set it in my tiapp.xml:

```
<icon>app_icon_512.png</icon>
```

Once the installation is complete, I have a nicely branded app icon.